# Clarification about "identifying" the points of a set

Tags: algebraic-topology

In  "algebraic topology,  an intuitive approach" by Hajime Sato, pg 10, it is said that if  we identify the boundary points of $D^n$ ( closed unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$) and regard them as a single point, i.e. by using the equivalence relation $x\sim y\iff  x,y\in \partial D^n$  ($\partial$ means boundary), then the quotient space $D^n/\sim$ is homeomorphic to $S^n$ ( unit circle in $\mathbb{R}^n$).

It seems to me that in the same intuitive way, the following also must be true. Suppose $A$ is a connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $E$ is the set of points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ having a distance $\leq 1$ from $A$. Then, by identifying the points of $A$, $E$ must be homeomorphic to $D^n$ and the boundary $\partial E$ must be homeomorphic to $S^n$. Is this "intuitive" way correct? If yes, what would be the first homomorphism here?

Comment: It might be worth your while to learn the rigorous approach to "identifying" points in a topological space, namely the theory of quotient spaces.

Comment: What's the meaning of “identifying the points of $A$” when $A\not\subset E$?

Comment: Sorry! I corrected.

Comment: What do you get if $A$ consists of two points?

Comment: Thanks. It seems to me that if the two points are considered as a single point, then      we obtain a closed disc (?)

Comment: Also "connected" is not enough, take $A=S^1\subset \mathbb R^2$, or a circle with larger radius

Comment: @M.Rahmat:  If you identify "the points of $A$" an the two points are far apart, you get two disks joined at their centers (and only their centers).  If the two points are close, you get something with the homotopy type of a circle.

Comment: Thanks. Are you saying that if, say, $A$ is a closed connected set, still $E/A$ doesn't have anything to do with $D^n$?